# Как находить ошибки в коде JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, отладка

Как находить ошибки в коде JavaScript?
Например, написал я скрипт, а он не работает. Если взять, например, Pascal, то там есть трассировка: жмёшь на пробел, и код построчно выполняется. Видно когда в цикл заходит, сколько раз там пробегается, когда из него выходит и другие вещи.

Comment: Открываете консоль браузера и смотрите, какие ошибки там появляются.

Comment: Если вы выполняете JS-код в браузере, то инструменты разработчика (включая консоль) вам в помощь.

Comment: есть аналог троссировки в дев тулс?

Comment: @Dimon трАссировка. Нашел [такую статью](https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome) с описанием инструментов.

Comment: @Dimon Call Stack – стек вызовов, все вложенные вызовы, которые привели к текущему месту кода.

Comment: @Regent можно сделать копипаст с указанием на источник и сделать доброе дело для ресурса с хорошим ответом)

Comment: Инструменты для проверки кода на потенциальные проблемы и ошибки называются линтеры, [**обзор линтеров для JavaScript на русском**](http://forwebdev.ru/javascript/linting/). Если работаете в Sublime Text, устанавливаете фреймворк SublimeLinter, затем плагин JSHint, [**видео по настройке**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVE3E9AvRag).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский судя по пункту 2.2 [пользовательского соглашения](https://learn.javascript.ru/agreement), просто скопировать, не ввязавшись в разборки, не получится. А самому с нуля писать статью про это "здоровья не хватит". Можно попытаться сделать вольный перевод [статьи с официального сайта](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: @Regent то, что там на сайте что-то написано - не значит ничего ибо для соглашения нужны две стороны, которые заключат договор на каком-то официальном уровне и заверят юр лицами. То, что я напишу - мою супермегакрутую разработанную игру не копировать - не имеет никакой силы без правильно оформленных договорных отношений. А так можно спокойно с каждого юзера деньги драть, который на ваш сайт зайдет, а у вас в пункте 3.0 будет написано что пользователь обязан заплатить 1000 руб. и что Каждым доступом к Сайту Пользователь соглашается соблюдать это условие

Comment: В ff есть неплохой дебагер [ссылка на видео](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools/Debugger). Аналогичные есть в хроме, опере, edje, ie с 9 (или 10) версии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моё имхо - Chrome Dev Tools это все что нужно. [Ссылка](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Конкретно про дебаг JS - [тут](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript)

Comment: + еще ссылка - https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 10):

### Линтеры

На раннем этапе, ещё до запуска приложения, очень помогают статические анализаторы кода, вот несколько из самых популярных:

- [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) от дедушки Крокфорда, создателя JSON. Попахивает валерьянкой, но вполне работает, не считая того, что настроек с гулькин нос.
- [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) отличный линтер с гибкими настройками, 6к звед на гитхабе.
- [ESLint](http://eslint.org/), и слитый с ним [JSCS](http://jscs.info/) пожалуй самая крутая штука, если нужно написать свои плагины для каких то специфических проверок.

Наверняка в вашу среду разработки можно их интегрировать так, чтобы они работали в фоне, и помечали найденные ошибки прямо в коде. Например для WebStorm достаточно просто поставить галку в настройках. Кстати, WebStorm имеет и свой собственный анализатор.

### Немного про типизацию

JavaScript не имеет (пока?) возможности указывать типы для аргументов функций, но можно воспользоваться, например, [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/). Пишите что-то вроде этого (обратите внимание на формат комментария):

```
/**
 * Creates a new Circle from a diameter.
 *
 * @param {number} d The desired diameter of the circle.
 * @return {Circle} The new Circle object.
 */
Circle.fromDiameter = function (d) {
    return new Circle(d / 2);
};
```

И теперь если где-то `fromDiameter` вызывается к примеру со строкой, то jsdoc в несложных случаях сможет это определить до запуска программы. В добавок к этому jsdoc дает ещё много разных плюшек, не считая основного предназначения - генерировать документацию по вашим комментариям.

Более брутальный вариант для настоящих бородатых гуру (например из команды AngularJS) взять и переписать все на TypeScript, который как JavaScript, но позволяет использовать (по желанию!) типы для переменных. И тогда, например, вы сразу увидите (по ошибке компилятора), что вызываете функцию, ожидающую строку, передав ей число.

### Отладка

Здесь старый добрый `Console.log('Ohh, shitt!')` никто не отменял. Но конечно же не стоит отказывать себе в удовольствии использовать продвинутые отладчики. Тот же WebStorm имеет вполне современные возможности по отладке, но и все мажорные браузеры имеют ту или иную "панель разработки", с отладчиком, профилировщиком и другими вкусностями. Ставите точки останова (и не простые, а с определенным хитрым условием, например чтобы остановилось только на второй раз, при спадающей луне), смотрите стек вызовов, значения переменных (меняете их налету по желанию) и т.п. Для быстрого старта в хроме - жмите `F12`, дальше разберетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял:

Вам нужно использовать [IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) для написания и редактирования кода.
Популярные IDE на данный момент разрабатывает компания JetBrains.

Конкретно под JavaScript можете использовать [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

При этом, в нём присутствует дебаггер, где можно настроить построчное выполнение кода.

Comment: ну, дебаггер и в браузере есть

Comment: @Dimon обновил. WebStorm называется IDE, а не phpStorm.

Comment: @nonews, phpstorm - Тоже ide

Comment: @Grundy я имел в виду то, что конкретная IDE под JS от JetBrains - WebStorm. Немного неверно выразился.

Comment: @nonews, насколько я помню, основное их отличие, что в phhstorm еще и php можно, а так одинаковые

Answer (score 1):

Лично я использую бесплатную кроссплатформенную [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). В ней есть отличный "пошаговый" дебаггер и всё необходимое.

Comment: не понимаю, как пользоваться  Visual Studio Code для джаваскрипта, хтмл и ксс. какие-то расширения надо ставить? как начать дебажить? вообще не понимаю, что с этой штукой  Visual Studio Code делать. где можно прочитать хорошее описание, как веб-разработчику с этим делом работать?

Comment: Её дебаггер используется для отладки javascript-скриптов на node.js, но есть так же [плагин для хрома](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome), позволяющий дебажить браузерный код. [Вот тут](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) всё расписано с картинками. :)

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Использовать IDE (WebStorm, к примеру)
2. Возможности браузеров (chrome dev dools, firebug, и т.д.)
3. Дебаг с помощью console.log (так себе способ).